# C++ Raylib Different Movement Speed at differents FPS even with DeltaTime

Tags: c++, timedelta, raylib

rigth now I try to make a small game with raylib and c++.
Rigth now I only have a small cube and a plain window with the FPS in the corner.
Becuase I doesnt wanted to use SetTargetFPS() I tried to implement deltaTime.

Rigth now I´m also calculating it and it works fine, when the FPS are stable, so for example:
The cube moves at stable 200 FPS as fast as at stable 60 FPS, but when I get rid of SetTargetFPS(), so I have unstable FPS and the jump between 2000FPS and 1000FPS, The movement speed isn´t good.

I calculate the deltaTime so:

```
oldTime = newTime;
newTime = GetTime();
deltaTime = (newTime - oldTime) * 500;
```

That does also work and I have pretty similar numbers at the sma FPS.

And that is how I move things:

```
newPosX = posX + addX * deltaTime;
```

Does somebody know why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to raylib but I believe the `GetFrameTime()` function is what you're looking for. This is the snippet in the [cheat sheet](https://www.raylib.com/cheatsheet/cheatsheet.html):

```
float GetFrameTime(void);        // Returns time in seconds for last frame drawn
```